# Android: scroll to the bottom of the view

Tags: android, listview, view, android-layout, scroll

I have a ListView containing some custom Views, and at the end of my list, a FooterView containing a Button.

When I click the button, it adds a view at the end of my ListView. But the cursor of the scrollbar stays at its position.

Now, what I want is to auto-scroll to the end of the list (so the user can see the new item).

Do you have any idea on how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you will  find you happyness [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720469/horizontalscrollview-auto-scroll-to-end-when-new-views-are-added)

Comment: Unfortunatly, it uses a ScrollView, and after some researches on Google, I've found that there is an unsolved issue with using a ListView inside a ScrollView (the ListView gets cut off).

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: There is no need to add a ListView in a ScrollView ,you can simply use a ScrollView :) , and add your Views to it:) and then you can autoScroll the ScrollView to the added view  when you click the Button add :)

Comment: That sounds good. I'm gonna try it tonight(I'm at work now). Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

ListView has a method just for this: [smoothScrollToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

Once you've added the new item, just calculate the length of the list and pass that (remembering zero-indexing) to the above method

Comment: I hadn't noticed this method.

The problem is that it has been added since Android 2.2 and I'm developping on an Android 2.1 device :(. 

I should consider upgrading my phone to Android 2.2(or 2.3) soon ^^.

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: did you find an answer for pre2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. it will solve your problem, i tried it and it works great.

```
listView.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
    listView.setSelection(listView.getCount() - 1);
}});
```