# Horizontal scroll view and focus on right side

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented `horizontalscrollview` and I am using `horizontalView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT` to focus on last element.

How I can do that in XML?

Comment: AFAIK, this is impossible. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720469/horizontalscrollview-auto-scroll-to-end-when-new-views-are-added/4720563#4720563

Comment: Why do you need it in XML anyway? This is something you do after adding the layout.