# Make horizontalscrollview auto scrolling

Tags: android, slide, marquee

I have multiple textviews inside a horizontalscrollview. Now I want to scroll all the textviews inside it so that all multiple textviews gets displayed. How can I achieve it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4720563/1208563

Comment: i want to loop the scroll. the link you provided set it to display at end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one git project. Its a scroller the scroll automatically and continously. It was made to show a credits screen by continously scrolling through a list of images.
This might help you or give you some idea.

https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo