# How to have a auto scrollable TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview, android-screen

I am trying to have a automatic scroll in android app.

Suppose that, I have xml code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="show me the texts"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

            </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In this xml code I have a Button on the top of the screen and a TextView which is wrapped by a ScrollView. It means that my TextView is scrollable right now.

It works correctly, because when the user touch the screen and swap down or up, the TextView can be scrolled up and down.

But...

I intend to have a Auto Scrollable TextView and by auto I mean, I need a scrollable TextView which scrolls down about 10dp after 10 seconds.

I know I must use some thread in my application for counting the time but I don't know how to say to TextView scroll down after 10 seconds for example.

any suggestions? Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720469/horizontalscrollview-auto-scroll-to-end-when-new-views-are-added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some thing like:

```
mScrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
             mScrollView.smoothScrollBy(10, 10);
        } 
});
```

Documentation for smoothScrollBy :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy(int,int)

To execute this task for every 10seconds:

```
TimerTask fileProcessTask = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Scrolling here
        }
    };

    Timer tm = new Timer();
    tm.schedule(fileProcessTask, 10000L);
```

Also take a look at this SO Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14685729/3326331 , I haven't tried it but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class File and paste the code below.

In your Layout.xml give Reference to `EllipsizingTextView` rather than using Android `TextView`.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 Micah Hainline
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Triposo
 * Copyright (C) 2013 Paul Imhoff     
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A {@link android.widget.TextView} that ellipsizes more intelligently. This class supports ellipsizing multiline text through setting {@code android:ellipsize} and {@code android:maxLines}.
 */
public class EllipsizingTextView extends TextView {
    private static final CharSequence ELLIPSIS = "\u2026";
    private static final Pattern DEFAULT_END_PUNCTUATION = Pattern.compile("[\\.!?,;:\u2026]*$", Pattern.DOTALL);
    private final List<EllipsizeListener> mEllipsizeListeners = new ArrayList<EllipsizeListener>();
    private EllipsizeStrategy mEllipsizeStrategy;
    private boolean isEllipsized;
    private boolean isStale;
    private boolean programmaticChange;
    private CharSequence mFullText;
    private int mMaxLines;
    private float mLineSpacingMult = 1.0f;
    private float mLineAddVertPad = 0.0f;

    /**
     * The end punctuation which will be removed when appending {@link #ELLIPSIS}.
     */
    private Pattern mEndPunctPattern;

    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }

    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] { android.R.attr.maxLines, android.R.attr.ellipsize }, defStyle, 0);
        setMaxLines(a.getInt(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        a.recycle();
        setEndPunctuationPattern(DEFAULT_END_PUNCTUATION);
    }

    public void setEndPunctuationPattern(Pattern pattern) {
        mEndPunctPattern = pattern;
    }

    public void addEllipsizeListener(EllipsizeListener listener) {
        if (listener == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        mEllipsizeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeEllipsizeListener(EllipsizeListener listener) {
        mEllipsizeListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public boolean isEllipsized() {
        return isEllipsized;
    }

    /**
     * @return The maximum number of lines displayed in this {@link android.widget.TextView}.
     */
    @SuppressLint("Override")
    public int getMaxLines() {
        return mMaxLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxLines(int maxLines) {
        super.setMaxLines(maxLines);
        mMaxLines = maxLines;
        isStale = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {        
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the last fully visible line is being ellipsized.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if the last fully visible line is being ellipsized; otherwise, returns {@code false}.
     */
    public boolean ellipsizingLastFullyVisibleLine() {
        return mMaxLines == Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
        mLineAddVertPad = add;
        mLineSpacingMult = mult;
        super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        if (!programmaticChange) {
            mFullText = text;
            isStale = true;
        }
        super.setText(text, type);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (ellipsizingLastFullyVisibleLine())
            isStale = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
        if (ellipsizingLastFullyVisibleLine())
            isStale = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (isStale)
            resetText();
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the ellipsized text if appropriate.
     */
    private void resetText() {
        int maxLines = getMaxLines();
        CharSequence workingText = mFullText;
        boolean ellipsized = false;

        if (maxLines != -1) {
            if (mEllipsizeStrategy == null)
                setEllipsize(null);
            workingText = mEllipsizeStrategy.processText(mFullText);
            ellipsized = !mEllipsizeStrategy.isInLayout(mFullText);
        }

        if (!workingText.equals(getText())) {
            programmaticChange = true;
            try {
                setText(workingText);
            } finally {
                programmaticChange = false;
            }
        }

        isStale = false;
        if (ellipsized != isEllipsized) {
            isEllipsized = ellipsized;
            for (EllipsizeListener listener : mEllipsizeListeners) {
                listener.ellipsizeStateChanged(ellipsized);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Causes words in the text that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. Use {@code null} to turn off ellipsizing.
     * 
     * @param where
     *            part of text to ellipsize
     */
    @Override
    public void setEllipsize(TruncateAt where) {
        if (where == null) {
            mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeNoneStrategy();
            return;
        }

        switch (where) {
        case END:
            mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeEndStrategy();
            break;
        case START:
            mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeStartStrategy();
            break;
        case MIDDLE:
            mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeMiddleStrategy();
            break;
        case MARQUEE:
            super.setEllipsize(where);
            isStale = false;
        default:
            mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeNoneStrategy();
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A listener that notifies when the ellipsize state has changed.
     */
    public interface EllipsizeListener {
        void ellipsizeStateChanged(boolean ellipsized);
    }

    /**
     * A base class for an ellipsize strategy.
     */
    private abstract class EllipsizeStrategy {
        /**
         * Returns ellipsized text if the text does not fit inside of the layout; otherwise, returns the full text.
         * 
         * @param text
         *            text to process
         * @return Ellipsized text if the text does not fit inside of the layout; otherwise, returns the full text.
         */
        public CharSequence processText(CharSequence text) {
            return !isInLayout(text) ? createEllipsizedText(text) : text;
        }

        /**
         * Determines if the text fits inside of the layout.
         * 
         * @param text
         *            text to fit
         * @return {@code true} if the text fits inside of the layout; otherwise, returns {@code false}.
         */
        public boolean isInLayout(CharSequence text) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(text);
            return layout.getLineCount() <= getLinesCount();
        }

        /**
         * Creates a working layout with the given text.
         * 
         * @param workingText
         *            text to create layout with
         * @return {@link android.text.Layout} with the given text.
         */
        protected Layout createWorkingLayout(CharSequence workingText) {
            return new StaticLayout(workingText, getPaint(), getWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mLineSpacingMult, mLineAddVertPad, false /* includepad */);
        }

        /**
         * Get how many lines of text we are allowed to display.
         */
        protected int getLinesCount() {
            if (ellipsizingLastFullyVisibleLine()) {
                int fullyVisibleLinesCount = getFullyVisibleLinesCount();
                return fullyVisibleLinesCount == -1 ? 1 : fullyVisibleLinesCount;
            } else {
                return mMaxLines;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get how many lines of text we can display so their full height is visible.
         */
        protected int getFullyVisibleLinesCount() {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout("");
            int height = getHeight() - getCompoundPaddingTop() - getCompoundPaddingBottom();
            int lineHeight = layout.getLineBottom(0);
            return height / lineHeight;
        }

        /**
         * Creates ellipsized text from the given text.
         * 
         * @param fullText
         *            text to ellipsize
         * @return Ellipsized text
         */
        protected abstract CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText);
    }

    /**
     * An {@link EllipsizingTextView.EllipsizeStrategy} that does not ellipsize text.
     */
    private class EllipsizeNoneStrategy extends EllipsizeStrategy {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText) {
            return fullText;
        }
    }

    /**
     * An {@link EllipsizingTextView.EllipsizeStrategy} that ellipsizes text at the end.
     */
    private class EllipsizeEndStrategy extends EllipsizeStrategy {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(fullText);
            int cutOffIndex = layout.getLineEnd(mMaxLines - 1);
            int textLength = fullText.length();
            int cutOffLength = textLength - cutOffIndex;
            if (cutOffLength < ELLIPSIS.length())
                cutOffLength = ELLIPSIS.length();
            String workingText = TextUtils.substring(fullText, 0, textLength - cutOffLength).trim();
            String strippedText = stripEndPunctuation(workingText);

            while (!isInLayout(strippedText + ELLIPSIS)) {
                int lastSpace = workingText.lastIndexOf(' ');
                if (lastSpace == -1)
                    break;
                workingText = workingText.substring(0, lastSpace).trim();
                strippedText = stripEndPunctuation(workingText);
            }

            workingText = strippedText + ELLIPSIS;
            SpannableStringBuilder dest = new SpannableStringBuilder(workingText);

            if (fullText instanceof Spanned) {
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) fullText, 0, workingText.length(), null, dest, 0);
            }
            return dest;
        }

        /**
         * Strips the end punctuation from a given text according to {@link #mEndPunctPattern}.
         * 
         * @param workingText
         *            text to strip end punctuation from
         * @return Text without end punctuation.
         */
        public String stripEndPunctuation(CharSequence workingText) {
            return mEndPunctPattern.matcher(workingText).replaceFirst("");
        }
    }

    /**
     * An {@link EllipsizingTextView.EllipsizeStrategy} that ellipsizes text at the start.
     */
    private class EllipsizeStartStrategy extends EllipsizeStrategy {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(fullText);
            int cutOffIndex = layout.getLineEnd(mMaxLines - 1);
            int textLength = fullText.length();
            int cutOffLength = textLength - cutOffIndex;
            if (cutOffLength < ELLIPSIS.length())
                cutOffLength = ELLIPSIS.length();
            String workingText = TextUtils.substring(fullText, cutOffLength, textLength).trim();

            while (!isInLayout(ELLIPSIS + workingText)) {
                int firstSpace = workingText.indexOf(' ');
                if (firstSpace == -1)
                    break;
                workingText = workingText.substring(firstSpace, workingText.length()).trim();
            }

            workingText = ELLIPSIS + workingText;
            SpannableStringBuilder dest = new SpannableStringBuilder(workingText);

            if (fullText instanceof Spanned) {
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) fullText, textLength - workingText.length(), textLength, null, dest, 0);
            }
            return dest;
        }
    }

    /**
     * An {@link EllipsizingTextView.EllipsizeStrategy} that ellipsizes text in the middle.
     */
    private class EllipsizeMiddleStrategy extends EllipsizeStrategy {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(fullText);
            int cutOffIndex = layout.getLineEnd(mMaxLines - 1);
            int textLength = fullText.length();
            int cutOffLength = textLength - cutOffIndex;
            if (cutOffLength < ELLIPSIS.length())
                cutOffLength = ELLIPSIS.length();
            cutOffLength += cutOffIndex % 2; // Make it even.
            String firstPart = TextUtils.substring(fullText, 0, textLength / 2 - cutOffLength / 2).trim();
            String secondPart = TextUtils.substring(fullText, textLength / 2 + cutOffLength / 2, textLength).trim();

            while (!isInLayout(firstPart + ELLIPSIS + secondPart)) {
                int lastSpaceFirstPart = firstPart.lastIndexOf(' ');
                int firstSpaceSecondPart = secondPart.indexOf(' ');
                if (lastSpaceFirstPart == -1 || firstSpaceSecondPart == -1)
                    break;
                firstPart = firstPart.substring(0, lastSpaceFirstPart).trim();
                secondPart = secondPart.substring(firstSpaceSecondPart, secondPart.length()).trim();
            }

            SpannableStringBuilder firstDest = new SpannableStringBuilder(firstPart);
            SpannableStringBuilder secondDest = new SpannableStringBuilder(secondPart);

            if (fullText instanceof Spanned) {
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) fullText, 0, firstPart.length(), null, firstDest, 0);
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) fullText, textLength - secondPart.length(), textLength, null, secondDest, 0);
            }
            return TextUtils.concat(firstDest, ELLIPSIS, secondDest);
        }
    }
}
```